# Correlation matrix in NumPy with NaN's

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, correlation

A have a `n x m` matrix in which row `i` represents the timeseries of the variable `V_i`. I would like to compute the `n x n` correlation matrix `M`, where `M_{i,j}` contains the correlation coefficient ([Pearson's r](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation)) between `V_i` and `V_j`.

However, when I try the following in numpy:

```
numpy.corrcoef(numpy.matrix('5 6 7; 1 1 1'))
```

I get the following output:

```
array([[  1., nan],
       [ nan, nan]])
```

It seems that `numpy.corrcoef` doesn't like unit vectors, because if I change the second row to `7 6 5`, I get the expected result:

```
array([[  1., -1.],
       [ -1.,  1.]])
```

What is the reason for this kind of behavior of `numpy.corrcoef`?

Comment: From my minute or two of reading the link on Pearson correlation, a constant function has undefined correlation. Is the 1,1,1 answer supposed to be wrong?

Comment: The numpy page on corrcoef says it's related to the numpy.cov function. Did you check whether that does what you expect?

Comment: i didn't know you could make a matrix that way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

leewangzhong (in the comment) is correct, Pearson's r is not defined for constant timeseries, as their standard deviation is zero. Thanks!